# wire service getRecord not working as expected

Tags: lightning-web-components, ui-record-api

```
import { LightningElement, track, api, wire } from 'lwc';

import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

const FIELDS = [
    'Task__c.Name'
];

export default class TaskEdit extends LightningElement {

    @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    task;

    get name() {
        console.log('this.task--', this.task);
        return this.task.data.fields.Name.value;
    }
. . .
```

I'm seeing data is undefined. What am I doing wrong here?

LWC is being called by an action

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>56.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
    </targets>
    <targetConfigs>
        <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
            <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
        </targetConfig>
    </targetConfigs>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: Are you using this component as Quick Action Button?

Comment: yessir - I'm trying your suggestion now

Answer (score 0):

I think your **recordId** is undefined, When you are using LWC component as Quick Action then you cannot get **recordId** from @api decorator because the url is changed.

If you want to get recordId you can use **CurrentPageReference**.

Like This :

```
import { CurrentPageReference } from 'lightning/navigation';

@wire(CurrentPageReference) getStateParameters(currentPageReference) {
        if (currentPageReference) {
            this.recordId = currentPageReference.state.recordId;
            console.log(this.recordId);
        }
    }
```

And then you can get Record Data.

Comment: the recordId is there and I'm still seeing undefined for data ------ [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'fields')]

Comment: can you take field apiName like this : import NAME from '@salesforce/schema/ObjectName.FieldName';

Comment: import NAME from '@salesforce/schema/Task__c.Name';

const FIELDS = [
    NAME
];
Still same result